# The process cannot access the file it is being used by another process c#

Tags: c#, filestream

I am using SaveFileDialog to save a pdf file.But at the creation of pdf file i am getting this error.

```
The process cannot access the file it is being used by another process c#
```

Here is my code in c#..

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 0;
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
    {
        // Code to write the stream goes here.
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, myStream);
        //myStream.Close();
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[myStream.Length];
            myStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)myStream.Length);
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            myStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error at this line..

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

Here is my pdf file code

```
        Stream myStream;

        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            pdfDoc.Open();
            pieChart.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            iTextSharp.text.Image chartImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream.GetBuffer());
            chartImage.ScalePercent(75f);
            pdfDoc.Add(chartImage);
        }
        pdfDoc.Close();
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the pdf open?

Comment: @user1714556 nope its closed

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
```

Here you open the file and then try to create it:

```
new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

Is myStream closed inside `GetInstance()` method? 
It is not. Otherwise you could not read from it inside using block:

```
myStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)myStream.Length);
```

You should either read all the contents of the file, close the stream and only after that recreate the file.
Another approach is to use temporary file to copy its contents.

Line by line:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // open the file to read its contents
    if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
    {
        // create NEW PDF object in memory
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

        // use memory stream for image
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // open pdf for changes
            pdfDoc.Open();
            // write image to memory stream
            pieChart.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            // create image instance from memory stream
            iTextSharp.text.Image chartImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream.GetBuffer());
            chartImage.ScalePercent(75f);
            // add the image to pdf document
            pdfDoc.Add(chartImage);
        }
        // close document... and forget about it. all changes were made in memory
        // pdfDoc will be collected by GC.
        pdfDoc.Close();

        // try to create new file with the name as already opened by myStream - Exception here
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[myStream.Length];
            myStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)myStream.Length);
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            myStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

What you should really do:

- Load PDF file. (`Document` probably contains static method `Load`/`LoadFrom` ore something like that.
- Change PDF like you do inside get instance.
- Save to file whatever you like. (`saveFileDialog1.FileName`)

Comment: Sir i have updated my post with pdf file code .Please help me suggest in that

Comment: @Ram myStream is not closed. It holds the handle to the file. opened file. And myStream is not closed but when you call new FileStream() with FileMode.Create you are trying to create the file with the same name as the file being read by myStream.

Comment: How and where to close myStream Sir

Comment: Let's define the goals first. You want to modify PDF, aren't you? Then  you should 1) Read data from the file, 2) Change it 3)write back.

You create PDF in memory, add image to it and then close. You don't save it do disk or as a stream of bytes in memory.

Effectively GetInstance does nothing with the file as far as I understand.

PDF api should contain method like 'SaveToFile()'

Comment: Yes sir exactly the same ,i want that pdf to be saved with SaveFileDialog box which is geving this error..

Comment: I updated the text of the answer. I'm afraid your expectations about what code does are wrong.

Comment: I am very sorry sir  but the-process-cannot-access-the-file-it-is-being-used-by-another-process still persists at the same line

Comment: @Ram. You have two distinct problems. 
1) You create and modify in-memory document and instantly lose all changes. You are not trying to save document.
2) You are trying to recreate already opened file.

Comment: Yes sir i want to save that changes and create a new file

Answer (score 0):

you are writig to the same file you are reading from. Hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Because at the time your `FileStream` is instantiated, your `(myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())` already has a handle open to the file.

You should use a single `StreamWriter` for this instead of messing around with mutliple streams.